# SQL server Update using JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I used this command in Sql Server to update a table using the maximum data in other table innerjoin

```
        UPDATE dbo.table2
        SET table2.LastGrantDate = max(table1.PlannedProjStartDate)
        from 
        table1 inner join table2
        on table2.Serial = table1.FundingEstablish
```

but it doesn't work

it workes only when I use it without the MAX() but

any way to solve this ??

Comment: But max command will always bring one value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a subquery.  Here is one way:

```
    UPDATE t2
    SET t2.LastGrantDate = t1.maxppsd
    from table2 t2 inner join
         (select FundingEstablish, max(PlannedProjStartDate) as maxppsd
          from table1
          group by FundingEstablish
         ) t1
         on t2.Serial = t1.FundingEstablish;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE t2
        SET t2.LastGrantDate = t1.PlannedProjStartDate
        from 
        table1 as t1 inner join 
(select FundingEstablish,max(PlannedProjStartDate) as PlannedProjStartDate
from table2 group by FundingEstablish) as t2
        on t2.Serial = t1.FundingEstablish
```